# how do I extract entries from a map inside an object wrapped in a Mono?

Tags: project-reactor

New to reactor and spring webflux, finding the paradigm shift quite hard.

I've got a `Mono<OAuth2User>`
It has a `Map<String, Object> getAttributes();`

I want to inspect the contents of the map.

I've broken it down to just trying to wrangle a map inside a Mono.

```
Mono<Map> mm = Mono.just(Map.of("a",1,"b",2,"c",3))
mm.log().map(m -> m.entrySet()).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable).map(e -> "key=" + e.getKey() + ",value=" + e.getValue() ).subscribe(System.out::println)
```

but I'm getting error:

```
ERROR: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getKey()
  location: variable e of type java.lang.Object
```

So why doesn't it just know that the type of the element is a Map.Entry?

edit: when I use keySet() or values() on the map, that works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example will work if you change declaration of `mm` to:

```java
Mono<Map<String, Integer>> mm = Mono.just(Map.of("a",1,"b",2,"c",3));
```

Comment: thanks Phil, that does the trick. I have upvoted but don't have the reputation for it to be seen.